# Call JSON C# classes into a method

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-api

I have a JSON API like this,

```
{
 "pokemon": {
 "currentPokemon": 1,
 "total": 1,
 "totalCount": 1,
 },
"collections": [
{
  "pokemonId": 2310,
  "pokemonName": "Pikachu",
  "pokemonType": "Land",
  "status": {
    "Active": "YES",
    "Holder": "ASH"
  },
  "power": {
    "Type": 10,
    "name": "Thunder"
  },

}
]
}
```

And I have the C# Classes for those API

```
Public ClassPokemonster 
{

public class RootObject
{
 [JsonProperty("pokemon")]
 public Pokemon Pokemon { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("collections")]
 public List<Collection> Collections { get; set; }
}
public class Pokemon
{
 [JsonProperty("currentPokemon")]
 public int CurrentPokemon { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("total")]
 public int Total { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("totalCount")]
 public int TotalCount { get; set; }
}
public class Collection
{
 [JsonProperty("pokemonId")]
 public int PokemonId { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("pokemonName")]
 public string PokemonName { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("pokemonType")]
 public string PokemonType { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("status")]
 public Status Status { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("power")]
public Power Power { get; set; }
}
public class Status
{
 [JsonProperty("Active")]
 public string Active { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("Holder")]
 public string Holder { get; set; }
}
public class Power 
{
 [JsonProperty("Type")]
 public int Type { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("name")]
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
}
```

And I'm trying to assert those values matching the API values using this method

```
         Driver.Instance.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        //WebRequest
        HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        getRequest.Method = "GET";

        var getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream newStream = getResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(newStream);

        //Deserialize JSON results
        var result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Pokemonster deserializedObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pokemonster>(result);
```

I'm trying to assert in this way,

```
  Assert.Equal("2310", deserializedObject.Collections.PokemonId.ToString());
```

My assert doesn't fetch the values inside the `collections` class such as `pokemonoId` `pokemonName`and so on!

Help me getting through this!

Comment: `deserializedObject.Collections` is a `List<Collection>`; it doesn't have a property named `PokemonId`. Did you mean `deserializedObject.Collections[0].PokemonId`?

Comment: Yes! Exactly you're right

Comment: There are a couple of other typos in your code. Please post the exact compile error.

Comment: Error CS1061 'List<Result>' does not contain a definition for **'pokemonId'** and no extension method **'pokemonId'** accepting a first argument of type 'List<Result>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue (it's probably just an issue with how you've formatted it here, but I should mention it for completeness) is that you have:

```
Public ClassPokemonster
```

But the correct syntax is:

```
public class Pokemonster
```

Next, notice that all your other classes are declared *inside* the class `Pokemonster`. This kind of structure is called a [**nested type**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The way you've designed it, the `Pokemonster` class itself contains no properties or methods, but the nested classes `Pokemonster.RootObject`, `Pokemonster.Pokemon`, etc. do have properties. So in order to correctly deserialize this type, you have to use:

```
Pokemonster.RootObject deserializedObjects = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pokemonster.RootObject>(result);
```

Finally, note that the property, `Pokemonster.RootObject.Collections` actually has the type `List<Pokemonster.Collection>`, but [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have any property named `PokemonId` (hence the error message). You'll have to access an item in this list to get any of it's properties, like this:

```
Assert.Equal("2310", deserializedObject.Collections[0].PokemonId.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks! The Magic worked! And how can I take the deserialized objects into a different class file ? Say, I have to move the assert statement into a different class and it throws up errors as well!

Comment: Your `Pokemonster` class and all its nested classes should be moved to its own code file (`Pokemonster.cs`), completely separate from any tests associated with it. Just make sure it's either in the same namespace or add the appropriate `using` statement where needed. If you're using Visual Studio, simply right-clicking on the project and selecting Add > Class... will give you a template of what you need.

Comment: Exactly! It is already that way. I wanted to seperate `webRequest , deserialize Json results` and `Asserts` into a different class. Meaning, I have three different classes as `Pokemonster.cs` , `API WebRequest` , and `Asserts`